# Can't click to focus a Canvas in an IFrame using Pixi.js

Tags: javascript, html, pixi.js

I'm building a web game with Pixi.js and it requires keyboard input. The problem is, when I upload my game it is presented within an IFrame and this seems to disable clicking on the canvas to give focus. If you click anywhere else in the IFrame but the canvas then the frame gets focus and recieves keyboard events.

I don't understand what is going on. How can I get around this behaviour?

This example is using arrow keys.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>* {padding: 0; margin: 0}</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/4.5.1/pixi.js"></script>
        <script>
            //Create the renderer
            var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(256, 256);
            
            //Add the canvas to the HTML document
            document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);
            
            //Create a container object called the `stage`
            var stage = new PIXI.Container();
            
            //Tell the `renderer` to `render` the `stage`
            renderer.render(stage);
            
            // Keys
            function keyboard(keyCode) {
                var key = {};
                key.code = keyCode;
                key.isDown = false;
                key.isUp = true;
                key.press = undefined;
                key.release = undefined;
                //The `downHandler`
                key.downHandler = function(event) {
                    if (event.keyCode === key.code) {
                        if (key.isUp && key.press) key.press();
                        key.isDown = true;
                        key.isUp = false;
                    }
                    event.preventDefault();
                };
                
                //The `upHandler`
                key.upHandler = function(event) {
                    if (event.keyCode === key.code) {
                        if (key.isDown && key.release) key.release();
                        key.isDown = false;
                        key.isUp = true;
                    }
                    event.preventDefault();
                };
                
                //Attach event listeners
                window.addEventListener(
                                        "keydown", key.downHandler.bind(key), false
                                        );
                window.addEventListener(
                                        "keyup", key.upHandler.bind(key), false
                                        );
                return key;
            }
            
            var left = keyboard(37),
                up = keyboard(38),
                right = keyboard(39),
                down = keyboard(40);
                
            left.press = function() { renderer.backgroundColor = 0x364669; renderer.render(stage); }
            up.press = function() { renderer.backgroundColor = 0xffffff; renderer.render(stage); }
            right.press = function() { renderer.backgroundColor = 0x000000; renderer.render(stage); }
            down.press = function() { renderer.backgroundColor = 0xff4600; renderer.render(stage); }
            
            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used something like this:

```
this.app = new PIXI.Application(width, height, { backgroundColor, resolution, antialias });
app.renderer.view.addEventListener('mousewheel', () => {
    if (window.parent === window) {
        window.focus();
    }
});
```

Seeing as the canvas is blocking the event with JavaScript `preventDefault()` or similar i.e. CSS's `touch-action`.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is supposed to work. I tried adding the event listener to the renderer in the snippet above. The results are the same, you can only focus the black square by clicking the grey or white border.